# Can I undo or delete some javascript code after running it

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am 3th year at college and for web design class we are manually drawing canvas elements. Which is very boring for me so I tried to make some 2D paint where I can do it by mouse where on the other end it writes code by itself.

I managed to do this much even tho is not "much" but now I am wondering is there a way to undo some script to remove it from the code? One way would be to append new canvas and do moves by one less but is there something to delete existing ones but not to  recreate new ones over and over again?

In this example down below (try by full screen), when I add new lines I add new moves to the array and when I finish at  the starting point I can draw new element. But every time I add new line I re create or draw lines over existing ones and new lines so it shows as one element where I could fill style and so on.
By doing that you will see that the adding lines over existing ones create a little darker bolder line, and because of that I would like to know if there is some way to delete or undo those lines and add whole new ones without puting em over existing ones.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var mainCanvas = $('#mainCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
 var coordsCanvas = $('#coordsCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
 var moves = [];
 $('#newCoords').click(function(){
  var mainCanvasWidth = $('#mainCanvas').width();
  $(this).parent().prepend('<input class="input-class" id="x-n0" placeholder="X number of blocks"><input class="input-class" id="y-n0" placeholder="Y number of blocks"> <span class="notes">Note: canvas full width is: '+Math.floor(mainCanvasWidth)+'px. </span><button id="saveCoords">Save</button>')
  $(this).remove();
 });

 $(document).on('click','#saveCoords',function(){
  var x = $(this).siblings('input#x-n0').val(),
   y = $(this).siblings('input#y-n0').val(),
   mainCanvasWidth = $('#mainCanvas').width(),
   mainCanvasHeight = $('#mainCanvas').height(),
   xWidthPx = Math.floor(mainCanvasWidth/x),
   yHeightPx = Math.floor(mainCanvasHeight/y);
   $('#coordsCanvas, #mainCanvas').attr('width', Math.floor(xWidthPx*x));
   $('#coordsCanvas, #mainCanvas').attr('height', Math.floor(yHeightPx*y));
   var marginLeftRight = 'calc(50% - '+Math.floor(xWidthPx*x)/2+'px)';
   $('#coordsCanvas, #mainCanvas').css({'width':Math.floor(xWidthPx*x)+'px','height':Math.floor(yHeightPx*y)+'px','left': marginLeftRight, 'top':'10vh'});
  for(var i=0; i<x-1; i++){
   coordsCanvas.beginPath();
   coordsCanvas.moveTo(Math.floor(xWidthPx+(xWidthPx*i)), 0);
   coordsCanvas.lineTo(Math.floor(xWidthPx+(xWidthPx*i)), Math.floor(yHeightPx*y));
   coordsCanvas.stroke();
   coordsCanvas.closePath();
  }
  for(var i=0; i<y-1; i++){
   coordsCanvas.beginPath();
   coordsCanvas.moveTo(0 ,Math.floor(yHeightPx+(yHeightPx*i))+1);
   coordsCanvas.lineTo(Math.floor(xWidthPx*x), Math.floor(yHeightPx+(yHeightPx*i))+1);
   coordsCanvas.stroke();
   coordsCanvas.closePath();
  }
  $(this).parent().html('<label for="#mouse-position"><input type="checkbox" id="mouse-position">Show mouse position</label><span class="notes">X = '+Math.floor(xWidthPx)+'px; Y = '+Math.floor(yHeightPx)+'px;</span><div class="tools"><button id="line">Lines</button></div>');
 });
 $(document).on( "change", "#mouse-position", function() {
  if($('input[id="mouse-position"]:checked').length === 1){
   $('#mouse-coords').css('display','block');
  }else{
   $('#mouse-coords').css('display','none');
  }
 });

 $(document).on( "click", "#line", function() {
  $(this).css('background','silver');
  $('#mainCanvas').css({'cursor':'url(./pen.png) 0 24, auto'});
 });
 $(document).on( "click", "#mainCanvas", function(e) {
  var cursor = $('#mainCanvas').css('cursor');
  var strokeStyle = $('#strokestyle').val(); 
  if(~cursor.indexOf('pen.png')){
   var posX = $(this).position().left,
             posY = $(this).position().top;
   if(moves[0]==='beginPath'){
    if(Object.keys(moves[1])[0]==='moveTo'){
     var len = moves.length-1,
      nowpos = Math.floor((e.pageX - posX)) + ',' + Math.floor((e.pageY - posY)),
      renderDrawing = [];
      renderDrawing.push({'func': 'beginPath', init: function(){ mainCanvas.beginPath(); }});
    if(moves[len]!=="stroke" || moves[len]!=="closePath"){

      for(var ee=1; ee<moves.length; ee++){
       if(Object.keys(moves[ee])[0]==="moveTo"){
        var mtp = moves[ee]['moveTo'],
        pos = mtp.split(',');
        renderDrawing.push({func: 'moveTo', val: pos, init: function(){
         mainCanvas.moveTo(this.val[0], this.val[1]);
        }});
       }else if(Object.keys(moves[ee])[0]==="lineTo"){
        var mtp = moves[ee]['lineTo'],
        pos = mtp.split(',');
        renderDrawing.push({func: 'lineTo', val: pos, init: function(){
         mainCanvas.lineTo(this.val[0], this.val[1]);
        }});
       }
      }
      var nowX = Math.floor((e.pageX - posX));
      var nowY = Math.floor((e.pageY - posY));
      var nowXY = nowX + ',' + nowY;
      moves.push({'lineTo':nowXY});
      renderDrawing.push(
       {func: 'lineTo', val: nowXY, init: function(){
        mainCanvas.lineTo(this.val.split(',')[0], this.val.split(',')[1]);
       }},
       {func: 'stroke', init: function(){ mainCanvas.stroke(); }},
       {func: 'closePath', init: function(){ mainCanvas.closePath(); }});
      for(var q=0; q<renderDrawing.length; q++){
       if(renderDrawing[q]['func']!=="beginPath" && renderDrawing[q]['func']!=="closePath" && renderDrawing[q]['func']!=="stroke"){
        renderDrawing[q].init();
       }else renderDrawing[q].init();
      }
      
      console.log(moves);
     if(Object.keys(moves[len])[0]==="lineTo" && nowpos===moves[1]['moveTo']){
      moves = [];
     }
    }
    }
   }else{
    mainCanvas.beginPath();
    mainCanvas.moveTo(Math.floor(e.pageX - posX) , Math.floor(e.pageY - posY));
    moves.push('beginPath',{'moveTo':Math.floor((e.pageX - posX)) + ',' + Math.floor((e.pageY - posY))});
    console.log(moves);
   }
  }
 });
 $(document).on('mousemove', "#mainCanvas", function(e){
  var parentOffset = $('#mainCanvas').offset(); 
  var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
  var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
  $('#mouse-coords').css({
   left:  e.pageX + 20,
   top:   e.pageY
  }).text( "X: " + Math.floor(relX) + ", Y: " + Math.floor(relY) );
 });
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 overflow: hidden;
 font-size: 100%;
}
.container {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 padding-right: 5vw;
 padding-left: 5vw;
 padding-top: 10vh;
 padding-bottom: 5vh;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}
canvas {
 width: 90vw;
 height: 85vh;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 float: left;
}
.toolsBar {
 width: calc(100% - 10vw);
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 left: 5vw;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 height: calc(10vh - 10px);
 overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
button {
 color: #fff;
 background: skyblue;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: left;
}
.input-class {
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 15px;
 float: left;
 border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
 outline: none;
}
.notes {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
 color: red;
 line-height: 60px;
}
#mouse-coords {
 position: absolute;
 display: none;
 background: #000;
 padding: 2px;
 color: #fff;
}
label[for="#mouse-position"] {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 60px;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 float: left;
 padding: 5px;
}
label>input {
 height: 1.2rem;
 width: 1.2rem;
}
.coordsCanvas {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100;
}
#mainCanvas {
 background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 200;
}
.tools {
 width: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-y: auto;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="toolsBar">
   <button id="newCoords">X & Y</button>
  </div>
  <div id="mouse-coords"></div>
  <canvas class="coordsCanvas" id="coordsCanvas"></canvas>
  <canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
 </div>
```

Comment: Some Serbian called Singidunum university, I know how it sounds like its such a shame to do that on 3th year....

Comment: @j08691 besides that can I get any help? :D